# print outside while prints twice python3

Tags: python-3.x

I have this assignment I have been working on

```
temperatures = []

def decision():
    answer  = input("Do you want to enter a temperature?" + 
        "\"y\" for yes. \"n\" for no: ")
    getTemp(answer)

def getTemp(answer):

    while answer == "y" or answer == "Y":
        temp = int(input("Enter a temperature: "))
        temperatures.append(temp)
        print("\nTemperature Entered!\n")
        answer = " "
        decision()

    print("Temperatures entered: ", temperatures)

def main():
    decision()

main()
```

The problem is when I enter a temperature then press n to exit the while loop, the final output is more than one print statement. For example if I input:(y's == yes)

```
y
3
y
5
n
```

the output is

```
Temperatures entered: [3,5]
Temperatures entered: [3,5]
Temperatures entered: [3,5]
```

Any help would be great...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `getTemp` is being called multiple times, due to it calling `decision`, which in turn calls `getTemp`. Instead, you should only print the temperatures after you exit the above chain, so you should move the `print` to after you call `decision` in `main`, so `main` should be:

```
def main():
    decision()
    print("Temperatures entered: ", temperatures)
```

and `getTemp` should be

```
def getTemp(answer):
    while answer == "y" or answer == "Y":
        temp = int(input("Enter a temperature: "))
        temperatures.append(temp)
        print("\nTemperature Entered!\n")
        answer = " "
        decision()
```

Comment: much appreciated! I ended up moving the print statement to main().

Answer (score 0):

You are recursing. If you ended up wanting to enter, say, 500000000 temperatures, you would definitely cause a stack overflow.

Your `print` executes at the end of each `decision()` execution. I suggest restructuring your code to not recurse (to save yourself from allocating forever) or at the very least put your `print` statement in your `main`.

For example, you could do [this](https://repl.it/repls/RevolvingSnowSearchservice)

```
temperatures = []

def decision():
  while input("Do you want to enter a temperature?\n" + 
      "\"y\" for yes. \"n\" for no: ") in "yY":
    getTemp()

def getTemp():
  temp = int(input("Enter a temperature: "))
  temperatures.append(temp)
  print("\nTemperature Entered!\n")

def main():
  decision()
  print("Temperatures entered: ", temperatures)

main()
```